# Google material design in dynamic page

Tags: material-design-lite

So, I am using infinite scroll (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/getting-started.html).

However when the main content is inside of "mdl-js-layout" the infinite scroll function does not work (shown below)

So, if I remove the `mdl-js-layout` in the most outer div, then infinite scroll works otherwise it does not work.

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
    Head
</head>
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_post_show">
        <?php
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        $args = array(              
            'paged'=>$paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,              
            'orderby' => 'date',            
            'order' => 'DESC'
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        global $post, $paged; 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div class="rhm_post_container">
            Post
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
    </div>
    <nav id="rh_nav_below">
        <ul>
            <li class="rh_nav_previous"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li class="rh_nav_next"><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</main>
</div>


<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#rhm_post_show');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.rhm_post_container',
  gutter: 10
});

var ias = $.ias({
  container:  '#rhm_post_show',
  item:       '.rhm_post_container',
  pagination: '#rh_nav_below',
  next:       '.rh_nav_next a',
  delay: 100
});

ias.on('render', function(items) {
  $(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
});

ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
  msnry.appended(items);
});

 ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
 ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align:center"><p><em>You reached the end!</em></p></div>'}));
 </script>
```

I asked the developer and got the following response:(https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1584#issuecomment-139060676)

> MDL is targeting static content for now, so use-cases with infinite scroll are not supported by us right now. However, there are people who have made MDL work with dynamic sites and you can probably get valuable help by heading over to StackOverflow and using the material-design-lite tag.

Does anyone what I should try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues with dynamic websites and mdl.

On their website I found the following paragraph about dynamic websites, which helped in my case:
https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic

`Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register new elements using the upgradeElement function.`

They also provide an example, how to use the function.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue on my side:

Material design locks the main wrappers height to 100%;

```
.mdl-layout__container .mdl-js-layout
```

this avoid masonry to keep loading more elements

so in your custom CSS add:

```
.mdl-layout__container, .mdl-js-layout{
  height: auto;
}
```